# Entity Framework 6 1-1 Navigation Property Always Loads

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-one, navigation-properties

I Have a Entity Class called Contact:

```
public class Contact{

    public int idContact { get; set; }
    public int id_Company { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool ShippingLocation { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Change> Changes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Entity> Entities1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

This is all OK. I have LazyLoading enabled in the context.

I wish to find out why, when I retrieve a list of Contacts, the `Company` property is always filled.

I understand the idea of LazyLoading, and you should specify the navigation properties to load using the `Include()` extension on the IQueryable (or ensure the Context is still available when accessing the property - otherwise ObjectDisposedException).

I would just like to know why EF is loading the 1-1 automatically, even if I don't specifically ask it to - the side effect of this is I have to now be careful when adding/updating contacts, as I am getting duplicate `Company` objects in the DB. That is, I have to manually set the `Company` to null or change its Entity state when updating the related entity.

Edit

This is how I populate the list of contacts:

```
public Dictionary<int, Contact> GetContacts(Func<T, TKey> selector)
    {
        using (DbContext db = new Context())
        {
          return context.Set<Contact>().ToDictionary(selector);
        }
    }
```

So, in theory I should get an `ObjectDisposedException` when I access the Company property, but I don't!

Comment: How did you know `loading automatically` ?

Comment: No, you don't understand lazy loading. When you specify what to load by `Include()` you are doing eager loading. Lazy loading is when you don't call the `include` and it automatically load the entity upon first access.

Comment: The `Company` object is populated when I view with the debugger.

Comment: Debugger also triggers lazy loading, you can check using profiler, the moment you check / hover the instance / property, the profiler will show there is a request to the database

Comment: In my case, whenever I view with debugger, the context is always disposed. Basically I fetch all data in using block.

Comment: @Simon, in that case you'll need to disable lazy loading and use `Include()` to *eager load* the related ends along with the entities.

Comment: The issue is I get the `Company` and I don't call Include() - I should either get an ObjectContextDisposed exception when I access the Company property, or it should be null. For Collection properties I don't have this issue!

Comment: Are you sure the virtual collection didn't throw objectdisposedexception? I just tried it, both virtual reference and virtual collection navigation will throw exception if object has been disposed, unless you have a code somewhere that access the collection before it has been disposed

Comment: Youd are wrong in your question lazzy loading is done automatically but Eager loading is done bye the help of Include() function call.Do you have your model classes in same project or you have a different class library project for classes if you have your libraries in different project added to your main project then plz check its settings.

Comment: @YuliamChandra - Thats what I am confused about - the collection's throw an exception, but the 1-1 doesn't!!!

Comment: there must be a code that accesses the company before the dbcontext is disposed, could be that `Func<T, TKey> selector` that refers to `Company` or other code that I'm not aware of

Comment: That behavior is correct.  Your debugger has to access the property to give you its value, and once it accesses it, the context loads it via lazy-loading.  Did you break *inside* the ``using`` block?  I think your understanding of "lazy-loading" is totally reverse.  What you want is done via turning **OFF** lazy-loading, not enabling it.

Comment: @YuliamChandra You are probably right, but I can't see it. The selector is simply `c => c.idContact`. so it must be somewhere else.

Comment: @StephenChung I break outside of the using block (otherwise the debugger will fetch it for me).

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile, as Dictionary can't be cast into the List return type.  Are you sure there is no more code?

Comment: There is a mountain of it, but that is a typo.

Comment: Only one line inside the ``using`` block?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59322/discussion-between-simon-and-stephen-chung).

Comment: Can you use SQL Profiler to see which SQL commands are executed and what data is being returned? Also, by monitoring "traffic" with the DB in this way, you'll see what gets executed when.

Comment: Would running this code in a `Task` have anything to do with it?

Comment: task shouldn't affect the lazy loading, try to use profiler, and debug per line `F10`, see which code that causes executing database something like `FROM [dbo].[Companies] AS [Extent1] WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @EntityKeyValue1`
`

Comment: @Simon The convention for `Entity Framework` is that the identity keys should be named `Id` or `EntitynameId` otherwise they are not recognized as such. I don't see  navigation property marking `id_company` as foreign key, so could that be an issue? I'm interested how your table looks like I think you should have a column named `id_company` and another, automatically created by the `EF` for FK to `Company`.

Comment: OK. So I've just removed the navigation property from the model. No code changes required - that would mean I didn't actually include it/reference it anywhere. Would it maybe be a data control that was using it??? Still I am baffled as what is/was going on here.

Comment: @Simon Just change `public int id_Company { get; set; }` to `public int CompanyId { get; set; }`, recreate your database and see if thsi gives you the desired behaviour. Genrally this is pretty straight forward so you just have to make sure that everything is matching the EF conventions (in your case the conventions for keys is not) or just start over again following some simple example how to create lazy loading with Code First in 1:1 relation. Excluding the mismatch in the names, your Entity seems fine.

Comment: I agree with the above suggestions.  Get the ``ObjectContext`` in the ``using`` block and print out the SQL sent to the db.  See if it only loads Contacts.